# JSON в Dataframe pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

Есть вот такой JSON получаемый по API

```
{
  "result": {
    "data": [
      {
        "dimensions": [
          {
            "id": "180062788",
            "name": "Кресло компьютерное игровое ThunderX3 EC3"
          },
          {
            "id": "2020-12-21",
            "name": ""
          }
        ]
      },
      "metrics": [
        14815,
        2
      ]
    },
```

```
df = pd.json_normalize(d2["data"],record_path='dimensions')
```

или

```
df = pd.json_normalize(d2["data"],record_path=['metrics'])
```

дает не верные результаты .

Я хотел бы получить такой  датафрейм :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не удивительно, что "дает неверные результаты" - я вот не вижу прямого соответствия ключей json с датафреймом

Comment: Я показал результат который хотел бы получить, но до него нужно ещё распарсить сам JSON, и вот там есть сложности как минимум в том что названия ключей одинаковы и парситься все в одну кучу. Тут и нужна помощь

Comment: Если вы не уверены в выборке, отдаваемой параметру record_path, попробуйте просто указать явно конечный уровень: `pd.json_normalize(d2['result']['data'][0]['dimensions'])`

Comment: Спасибо вот это решение позволяет забирать данные из второго массива dimensions, вот только почему то работает только с первой строкой а нужно спарсить все значения, в каком направлении смотреть ?

Comment: из за того что в dimensions вложено два массива с одинаковыми и именами но разным смыслом pd.json_normalize(d2['data'],record_path=['dimensions']) парсит сразу обо массива, можно ли как то в record_path указать какой именно массива парсить ?

Comment: Укажите индекс элемента. То есть ["dimensions"] [0] например

Comment: так и делаю. но результат => датафрейм только из первой строки